# Logrotation performance

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, apc, log-rotation

One question about logrotation on a dedicated webserver (64gb RAM) with apache and mysql. In high load hours (2k users online every moment) we are experiencing a strange behaviour.

As an example, at 16:30 we have 1850 users, low ram utilisation (20gb), no slow queries logged and everything is working fine.

At 16:50, logs rotate.

At 16:53, the server begins crashing and cannot handle anymore the users. Page load becomes incredibly slow, and goes worse until we manually restart apache.

As we are under apc and as far as i know logrotation causes apache to reload, may the logrotation be the cause of degradation in performance? Maybe because of clearing apc's cache?

Here the logrotate configuration:

`/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}`

and the top I/O using processes

`----total-cpu-usage---- -most-expensive- -dsk/total- ----most-expensive----
usr sys idl wai hiq siq|  cpu process   | read  writ|  block i/o process
  3   0  97   0   0   0|mysqld       0.6|1984B  430k|mysqld       16B  297k
  3   0  96   0   0   0|mysqld       0.8|   0   732k|mysqld        0   584k
  6   1  94   0   0   0|mysqld       0.6|   0   104k|mysqld        0   312k
  4   1  96   0   0   0|apache2      0.6|   0   196k|rotatelogs    0  4096B
  4   1  94   0   0   0|apache2      1.5|   0   452k|jbd2/sda2-8   0   284k
  3   1  96   0   0   0|apache2      1.4|   0   240k|jbd2/sda2-8   0   104k
  5   1  95   0   0   0|mysqld       1.1|   0     0 |apache2       0  4096B
  6   1  93   0   0   0|apache2      1.2|   0   252k|jbd2/sda2-8   0    96k
  3   1  96   0   0   0|apache2      0.5|   0  4260k|apache2       0  1768k
  7   1  93   0   0   0|apache2      1.8|   0   436k|apache2       0   648k
  5   1  94   0   0   0|mysqld       1.1|   0    12k|apache2       0    12k
  2   0  98   0   0   0|apache2      0.2|   0  1180k|mysqld        0  1032k
  6   1  92   0   0   0|apache2      1.5|   0   480k|mysqld        0   664k
  4   0  96   0   0   0|apache2      0.5|   0   312k|rotatelogs    0  8192B
  5   0  95   0   0   0|mysqld       0.9|   0     0 |apache2       0  4096B
  3   1  95   0   0   0|apache2      0.6|   0   516k|mysqld        0   308k
  4   1  95   0   0   0|apache2      0.9|   0   316k|mysqld        0   296k
  6   0  93   0   0   0|apache2      2.1|   0   332k|jbd2/sda2-8   0   176k
  5   1  94   0   0   0|apache2      1.6|   0   420k|apache2       0    40k
  3   0  96   0   0   0|mysqld       0.8|   0     0 |mysqld        0   412k
  5   0  94   0   0   0|apache2      2.1|   0   188k|jbd2/sda2-8   0    52k
  8   1  91   0   0   0|apache2      2.1|   0   544k|apache2       0   232k
  7   0  93   0   0   0|mysqld       1.2|   0  2020k|mysqld        0  2228k
  3   0  96   0   0   0|mysqld       0.6|   0   212k|rotatelogs    0  4096B
  3   0  97   0   0   0|apache2      0.6|   0     0 |apache2       0  8192B
  6   0  94   0   0   0|apache2      1.8|   0   320k|jbd2/sda2-8   0   120k
  7   1  92   0   0   0|mysqld       1.6|   0   656k|mysqld        0   832k
  6   0  93   0   0   0|mysqld       1.2|   0   312k|jbd2/sda2-8   0    80k
  6   1  94   0   0   0|apache2      1.2|   0   548k|jbd2/sda2-8   0   140k
  5   0  95   0   0   0|apache2      1.5|   0   128k|jbd2/sda2-8   0    20k
  4   0  95   0   0   0|apache2      1.6|   0   152k|jbd2/sda2-8   0    36k
  2   0  98   0   0   0|mysqld       0.4|   0    12k|apache2       0  4096B`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the logrotate config look like? Can you see any disk I/O issues related to those times?